# Clustering algorithms that operate on sparse data matricies

Tags: r, clustering, sparse

I'm trying to compile a list of clustering algorithms that are:

1. Implemented in R
2. Operate on sparse *data matrices* (not (dis)similarity matrices), such as those created by the [sparseMatrix](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/functions/sparseMatrix) function.

There are several other questions on CV that discuss this concept, but none of them link to R packages that can operate directly on sparse matrices:

1. [Clustering large and sparse datasets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10411/clustering-large-and-sparse-datasets)
2. [Clustering high-dimensional sparse binary data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44640/clustering-high-dimensional-sparse-binary-data)
3. [Looking for sparse and high-dimensional clustering implementation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10122/looking-for-sparse-and-high-dimensional-clustering-implementation)
4. [Space-efficient clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9778/space-efficient-clustering/)

So far, I've found exactly one function in R that can cluster sparse matrices:

## [skmeans](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/skmeans/functions/skmeans): spherical kmeans

From the [skmeans package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skmeans/index.html). kmeans using [cosine distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).  Operates on dgTMatrix objects. Provides an interface to a genetic k-means algorithm, pclust, CLUTO, gmeans, and kmndirs.

Example:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(42)

nrow <- 1000
ncol <- 10000
i <- rep(1:nrow, sample(5:100, nrow, replace=TRUE))
nnz <- length(i)
M1 <- sparseMatrix(i = i,
                   j = sample(ncol, nnz, replace = TRUE),
                   x = sample(0:1 , nnz, replace = TRUE), 
                   dims = c(nrow, ncol))
M1 <- M1[rowSums(M1) != 0, colSums(M1) != 0]

library(skmeans)
library(cluster)
clust_sk <- skmeans(M1, 10, method='pclust', control=list(verbose=TRUE))
summary(silhouette(clust_sk))
```

---

The following algorithms get honerable mentions: they're not quite clustering algorithms, but operate on sparse matrices.

## [apriori](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/functions/apriori): association rules mining

From the [arules package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html). Operates on "transactions" objects, which can be coerced from ngCMatrix objects.  Can be used to make recommendations.

example:

```
library(arules)
M1_trans <- as(as(t(M1), 'ngCMatrix'), 'transactions')
rules <- apriori(M1_trans, parameter = 
list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.01, target = "rules"))
summary(rules)
```

## [irlba](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/irlba/functions/irlba):  sparse SVD

From the [irlba package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irlba/index.html).  Does SVD on sparse matrices.  Can be used to reduced the dimensionality of sparse matrices prior to clustering with traditional R packages.

example:

```
library(irlba)
s <- irlba(M1, nu = 0, nv=10)
M1_reduced <- as.matrix(M1 %*% s$v)
clust_kmeans <- kmeans(M1, 10)
summary(silhouette(clust_kmeans$cluster, dist(M1_reduced)))
```

## [apcluster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/index.html):  Affinity Propagation Clustering

```
library(apcluster)
sim <- crossprod(M1)
sim <- sim / sqrt(sim)
clust_ap <- apcluster(sim) #Takes a while
```

What other functions are out there?

Comment: Do you mean sparse as in "lots of zeros" or as in "lots of missing values"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic according to multiple criteria at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: every answer would be equally valid, you expect more answers in addition to those provided, and there is no actual problem to be solved.

Comment: I realise this got closed, but I've been tripping over all your questions on this as I browse SO as I had a similar problem ;)  I found this library which uses affinity propensity that can work with sparse matrices: http://www.bioinf.jku.at/software/apcluster/

Comment: @MarkeD Thanks a lot!  It's really too bad software recommendations are off-topic here, as I've found nowhere else online to ask for them.

Comment: @MarkeD Could you post an example with the M1 matrix in my question above?  I can't seem to get apcluster to run on that matrix in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Zach ahh sorry should have put more context in the comment ;) The algo only runs in reasonable time on small data sets but doesn't care about "lots of zero" matrices - I run it on a sample and it then outputs "examplers" which for your big matrix case you could then use as a start point for k-means. So not dimension reduction etc. but alt approach(?)

Comment: I'll just mention mcl (http://micans.org/mcl), as that algorithm is actually closely tied to sparse matrices; it is most naturally formulated in the language of matrix operations and utilises sparse matrices in the implementation. It is a custom C implementation (not directly available in R, although people have written R interfaces to the external mcl process), quite widely used in bioinformatics.

Comment: once again very useful question is closed :( if you dont know the answer just dont vote for close!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use R. It is often very slow and has next to no indexing support.
But software recommendations are considered off-topic anyway.

Note that *plenty* of algorithms don't care how you store your data. If you prefer to have a sparse matrix, that should be your choice, not the algorithms choice.

People that use too much R tend to get stuck in thinking in matrix operations (because that is the only way to write fast code in R). But that is a limited way of thinking. For example k-means: it doesn't care. In particular, it doesn't use pairwise distances at all. It just needs a way to compute the variance contribution; which is equivalent to computing the squared Euclidean distance.

Or DBSCAN. All it needs is a "neighbor" predicate. It can work with arbitrary graphs; it's just that Euclidean distance and the Epsilon threshold is the most common way of computing the neighborhood graph it uses.

P.S. Your question isn't very precise. Do you refer to **sparse data matrixes** or **sparse similarity matrixes**?

Comment: sparse data matrixes

Comment: Most algorithms can operate on sparse data matrixes. E.g., AGNES, PAM, DBSCAN, OPTICS, CLARA, ...

Comment: Not sure why you even answered if you don't even know R.

Comment: I know R. Probably even better than the average R user. I know non-standard evaluation in R and I know that most of the modules are written in C, so when you pass a sparse matrix, it is first copied into a sense matrix before passing it to the actual code. And every package uses a different way of doing so... That is not efficient. You don't choose R if you need efficiency or good integration or backwards compatibility or coordinated development.